# xcode7にしてCannot assign a value of typeでエラーが出ます

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

delegate側 
`var id:Int?`

色々なコード 
`appdelegate.id = self.data[indexPath.row]["id"] as Int`

APIからとってきた大切なデータをdelegateに保存したいのですが 
`Cannot assign a value of type Int to a value of type Int?`
と出てしまいます。

他にもNameを保存したいコードだとstringなので 
`Cannot assign a value of type String to a value of type String?`

と出てしまいます。

xcode7にしてから出てきたエラーなので対処方法がわかりません。 
宜しくお願いします

Answer (score 1):

> xcode7にしてから出てきたエラーなので対処方法がわかりません。

Xcode 6.3から変更になっている部分、Swiftのバージョンでいうと1.2からの変更です。Appleの公開文書に、直接あたってください。

[Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/) Feb 18, 2015

Swift 1.2よりダウンキャストの書式が変更になりました。Optional型へのダウンキャストは、「as」から「as?」になります。

```
appdelegate.id = self.data[indexPath.row]["id"] as Int
```

これは

```
appdelegate.id = self.data[indexPath.row]["id"] as? Int
```

とすれば、エラー表示が出なくなるはずです。

Comment: 前までそれで動いていたのですが、xcode7 betaを入れて開いた時に質問のエラーが出て消えないです・・・
それにした結果は
```Cannot assign a value of type Int? to a value of type Int?```
となります
alamofireとswiftyJsonのエラーがでたのでpod updateはしました。
libcc++.dylibも見つからなかったので、libc++.1.dylibを読み込んでます。
deploy targetは9.0にしてます。